# Is AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID required?

Tags: iphone, audiotoolbox

I recently started working with the AudioToolbox framework and noticed that there is a method called `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()`.

Just to know, is it a memory leak not to call the above method when calling `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()` to init my `SystemSoundID`? I am calling it like:

`AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &sound);`

That way filePath being a NSURL and sound `SystemSoundID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Call it when you're done with `sound`. Otherwise, you may leak any memory associated with `sound` (which can be significant for A/V files.)

Comment: I am actually using it with an AIF file.

Comment: A/V = "audio/video". AIF falls under that category.

Comment: I got that :p Although I thought you meant 'signigicant for *some* A/V files'

Comment: It varies from file to file. That's an implementation detail. Call `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()` anyway when you no longer need the system sound.

Comment: As described in this question, the sound is not played when AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID() is called directly afterwords.
Any hints about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614179/ios-8-audioservicesplaysystemsound-is-not-playing-sound-when-audioservicesdispo