# iOS 8: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is not playing Sound when AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID is called afterwards

Tags: ios, audio

When calling **AudioServicesPlaySystemSound**, it plays well the previous created SystemSound. But when i call **AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID** directly afterwards, the sound is not played. It seems as the Sound-Resource is disposed before it would have been played.

But on [this Stackoverflow-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728057/is-audioservicesdisposesystemsoundid-required) the people say, that it is necessary to dispose the System-Sound to avoid memory leaks.

How is the correct way for both methods? Shall i call the Dispose-Method with a timer some seconds later? Or create a singleton which creates the Sound-Resource once at the first call of the Play-Method and dispose the Resource at dealloc of the singleton?

```
- (void) playSound {
    NSURL *url   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"SentMessage"
                                           withExtension: @"wav"];

    SystemSoundID mBeep;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url,  &mBeep );

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mBeep);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(mBeep);  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` to register a callback to be called when your sound finishes playing. You could dispose of the system sound there.

Or in your class's `dealloc`.